# Express.js / JWT Tokens - res.cookie with secure

Tags: cookies, jwt, token, ejs

I am using JWT tokens for my backend API. I am using the following code to set cookie when the user first logs in.

```
res.cookie("SESSIONID", token , { httpOnly: true, secure: true });
```

However, this does not save the cookie (jwt token) in the browser. I tried to remove the "secure: true" in the options above, and the program works fine.

My question is, what does secure: true do and is this the correct method to secure the application with JWT. I am using NodeJS and ExpressJS as the backend and EJS as the frontend templating engine.

Thank you!

Comment: A secure cookie is only sent to the server with an encrypted request over the HTTPS protocol

Comment: The secure property marks the cookie to be used with HTTPS only. Documentation: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie